# How can I use Python to parse html tags to Unicode characters

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing

I have an XML document with html markup in some text elements like this:

```
<my-element><p>This is an XML element<br/>
with HTML markup and chemical formulas <br/>
like water H<sub>2</sub>O, scientific notation like 1.32 x 10<sup>4</sup>, and other super- and <br/>
sub-script c<sub>h</sub><sup>a</sup><sub>r</sub><sup>a</sup>c<sub>t</sup><sub>e</sub><sup>r</sup><sub>s</sub> <sup>i</sup><sup>n</sup> Unicode.</p></my-element>
```

I'm using lxml's xtree. The parser has two xml and html modes, but I haven't found a way to parse the complete text string (paragraph) to render as Unicode characters like this:

```
This is an element
with HTML markup and chemical formulas 
like water H₂O, scientific notation like 1.32 x 10³, and all super- and 
sub-script cₕₐᵣₐcₜₑᵣₛ ⁱⁿ Unicode.
```

Is there some other library that an help?

Comment: The set of available unicode super & subscripts appears to be not complete: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts So independent of the programming language, you won't be able to represent all sub&superscripts that you can render with html.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian, that's helpful. Does anyone know of any Python libraries that do the conversion for the existing Unicode characters, or will I have to roll my own?